# Software for writing pages with pictures and custom shaped text fields

Tags: ebooks, writing

What I'm thinking is specifically to be able to add a background to the page, a picture in the middle, and for instance shape my text to go around the picture in a circle, or perhaps that it is straight, but leaves an empty circle in the middle.

Perhaps what I'm thinking is the ability to designate the specific area in which text is allowed. Like draw a wiggly box, and the text would only go up to the wiggle edge line, so the text paragraph would be wavy in the end.

Features like this

Comment: What is the application for this - web page, printed document, ebook (and if ebook, what platform), something else?

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin eBook most likely. I want to export it in PDF format mainly

Comment: If you're targetting PDF, then there's plenty of software out there that will let you do this - what OS are you working on? For Windows, *I* would use Microsoft Publisher, but any document layout/Desktop Publishing program (e.g., PageMaker, QuarkXPress, InDesign, Scribus...) should do you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Microsoft PowerPoint** for that, it would let you do all the things that you have mentioned in this post and in addition you can **save it as pdf, website or in whatever format, that you want**.

Comment: Plus, MS print to PDF. Good suggestion - although I am not sure if it flows text around shapes